# SSRS expression issue using Sum and IIF

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

In SSRS I am trying to SUM a field, based on the value of another field.

Example:
 If field Title Q1 is Value 1 and Title IsCompletedOnTime is Value 1, I need a total for Title Q1 Valiue 1.

Below is the expression I wrote. However, I get a syntax error for the "." .

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Qtr 1.Value = "1",0, (IIF(Fields!IsCompletedOnTime.Value = "1",0))))
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a space between Qtr and 1

Comment: You are correct. There should not be a space. However, I closed the space, but now get a syntax is incorrect error.

Comment: the 2nd IIF doesn't have a `False` part either

Comment: I would rewrite the logic in the SQL as a case statement.

Comment: I tried rewriting the logic with 2 different expressions, but neither works. 


    =SUM(IIF(Fields!Quarter.Value="Q1" AND Fields!IsCompletedOnTime.Value= "1",Fields!Q1Completed.Value,1))


=IIF(SUM(Fields!Quarter.Value="Q1" AND Fields!IsCompletedOnTime.Value= "1",Fields!Q1Completed.Value,1))


Suggestions please.